# Change colours of syntax highlighting in Geany

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, geany

I have two computers, each with Geany. One has the colour scheme that I like for Python, the other one has some sort of basic scheme with only keywords highlighted. I've looked and looked without any success at `filetypes.python` and `filetypes.common`. There's nothing in colorschemes apart from `alt.conf`.

Where do I find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you do for Geany versions 20 and 21.

1. Find which version of Geany you have (menu *Help* → *About*).
2. Visit this site:
   https://github.com/codebrainz/geany-themes
3. Scroll to **Introduction** section and download a file for your Geany version:

- *geany-themes-0.20.zip* - for version 20
- *geany-themes-0.21.1.zip* - for version 21

4. Unzip the downloaded file and navigate to its **colorschemes** directory. You will see a bunch of files with `.conf` extention. Copy all of them to `~/.config/geany/colorschemes/` (if you're on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)) or to `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\geany\colorschemes` (if you're on Windows)
5. Then copy all the files from unzipped **filedefs** directory into your `~/.config/geany/filedefs/` (Ubuntu), or into `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\geany\filedefs` (Windows).

If you do not have such directories in your Geany installation you'd want to create them manually.

Launch Geany and enjoy the themes!

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at these and I must be missing something simple because it doesn't help me to get started

Comment: Just updated the answer. Hope this helps! PS You did check out **View -> Change Color Scheme...** menu, right?

Comment: Can you include [how to actually select a theme](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/03/29/using-geany/) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar)? *"menu View → Change Colour Scheme…"*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In `filetypes.python` (can be opened from menu *Tools* → *Configuration Files* → *Filetype Configuration* → *Scripting Languages*), section `[styling]`. Colors are coded in hexadecimal.

Comment: In filetypes.python [styling] it simply says "edit these on the colorscheme.conf file instead". In the colorschemes directory, there is only one file alt.conf and it is the same of both computers. Changing that has no effect